# manipulate json array in angular

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

How can I print a specific value from an array in typescript? I have the following code in typescript:

```
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {
    myArray: any[] = [];

    constructor(public afs: AngularFirestore) {}
    emailtoprint = "sadasd@assf.co";

    test = this.afs.collection('doctors').get().subscribe((ss) => {
        ss.docs.forEach((doc) => {this.myArray.push(doc.data()); });
     });
}
```

email for emailtoprint is printed in html like this:

```
<div *ngFor='let i of myArray'>
    <div *ngIf="i.email == emailtoprint">{{i.email}}</div>
</div>
```

As you can see, I was able to find the corresponding email with ngIf... Although, it is not really optimal if myArray has a lot of values. I would like to know how can I get a specific values from an array in typescript angular? I tried the following but I get an empty output:

```
test3 = this.myArray.find(e => e.email === emailtoprint);
```

Here is the entitiy found for myArray when I do

```
<li *ngFor="let i of myArray">
   {{i | json}}
</li>
```

{ "firstName": "Df", "lastName": "Sdf", "email": "sadasd@assf.co"}

{ "firstName": "Anna", "lastName": "Sims", "email": "doctor@hotmail.com"}

{ "firstName": "John", "lastName": "Adad", "email": "nurse@hotmail.com" }

Comment: May we know the sample data in your this.myArray? :) Since your .find() is right and i think there maybe something inside the this.myArray data that might be overlooked in regards to it's structure

Comment: I updated my question to show my array data. From another angle, I think it would be best if I can only get the column in the database with the emailtoprint, when I do `test = this.afs.collection('doctors').get().subscribe((ss) => {
        ss.docs.forEach((doc) => {this.myArray.push(doc.data()); });
     });` but I don't know how to do that

Comment: What all information do you need from `myArray`?

Comment: I just need the column of sadasd@assf.co

Comment: I tried the following but it prints [Object object] `test2 = this.afs.collection('doctors', ref => ref.where('email', '==', this.email));`

Comment: What is `emailtoprint`?

Comment: emailtoprint is the value I am trying to find in my array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't assign a `variable` in your service call that is being subscribed to. Instead you can implement it like this.

You can use either of these methods:

**Method #1**

```
this.afs
   .collection('doctors')
   .get()
   .subscribe(({ docs }) => {

      // Replicating what you did by and invoking the data function 
      const data = docs.map(({ data }) => data());

      // If you use .find() , it will give you an object which you can't loop through
      this.myArray = data.find(({ email }) => email === this.emailtoprint);

      // or
    
      // If you use .filter(), it will give you an array, but i say if finding only 1 data, it's best to use .find
      this.myArray = data.filter(({ email }) => email === this.emailtoprint);


      // Console to check the result
      console.log(this.myArray);
    });
```

**Method #2**

or if you want to still get the original array of data and have a separate variable for the email match, you can do this instead:

```
userMatch: any;

...
.subscribe(({ docs }) => {
   this.myArray = docs.map(({ data }) => data());

   this.userMatch = this.myArray.find(({ email }) => email === this.emailtoprint);


   // Console and check the data
   console.log(this.myArray);
   console.log(this.userMatch);
});
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, although I still don't have anything printing with both methods... I tried to print the object userMatch like this in html : `<div>{{userMatch}}<div>` and nothing appears

Comment: Have created a sample stackblitz demo for your reference but im assuming here that the return result from the service call is an array, but it may be best to know if I can know the structure of your sample response from your "this.afs.collection('doctors').get()"  to conform with the stackblitz demo sample. Here's the link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-sampe-data?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Find will fetch you one object but you need to filter on the bases of the email so replace find() with filter() like :

```
test3 = this.myArray.filter(e => e.email === emailtoprint);
```